# How I can select an element from a dropdown list?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

**Problem:** I try to select an element from a dropdown list

I have a dropdown list with the following HTML code:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap localitate">
<select name="localitate" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select form-control" id="cf_location_trigger" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="">Locatie</option>
<option value="Bucuresti CARAMFIL">Bucuresti CARAMFIL</option>
<option value="Bucuresti THE LIGHT">Bucuresti THE LIGHT</option>
<option value="Cluj-Napoca">Cluj-Napoca</option>
<option value="Iasi">Iasi</option></select></span>
```

**I try to select the element with the following Java code but didn't work:**

```
 location.click();
   
   WebDriverWait waits = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
   waits.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cf_location_trigger\"]"))).click();
           Select dropdownLocation = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cf_location_trigger\"]")));
           dropdownLocation.selectByIndex(3);
```

How I can select the element,I tried to increase the time in Wait, I also tried with `Thread.sleep ()` but it still doesn't recognize the items in the list or  `dropdownLocation.selectByText("Bucuresti CARAMFI");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dropdownLocation.selectByText("Bucuresti");
```

I don't see any option text as `Bucuresti`

try replacing with that :

```
Bucuresti CARAMFIL
```

Adding few more things :

```
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cf_location_trigger\"]"))).click();
```

You do not need to `click` on Select `WebElement` since it will be taken care by `Select` class that you have used.

You should use **id**, *do not use ID with XPATH.* until it's necessary.

Something like this :

```
Select dropdownLocation = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cf_location_trigger")));
```

**Update 1 :**

**Code in sequence :**

```
Select dropdownLocation = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cf_location_trigger")));
dropdownLocation.selectByText("Bucuresti CARAMFI");
```

**Udpate 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("cf_location_trigger")))).build().perform();
Select select = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("cf_location_trigger"))));
select.selectByVisibleText("Bucuresti CARAMFI");
```

Comment: The program is running, but cannot identify the item. Click on the "Location" dropdown but do not access the "Bucharest CARAMFIL" element

Comment: I tried with xpath, css, id, tagname locators and....nothing

Comment: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1623151401.636][WARNING]: Deprecated chrome option is ignored: useAutomationExtension
[1623151401.636][WARNING]: Deprecated chrome option is ignored: useAutomationExtension
[1623151402.086][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 91.
Jun 08, 2021 2:23:22 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1052, 3403)
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: that means driver is not able to move to drop down.. where is this drop down in UI ? is it in view port ? Do you have to do scroll to see this drop down ?

Comment: The dropdown is in UI. I added the image in description

Comment: I also tried with JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");

Comment: This image does not tell where it's located in UI. You need to show in UI where it's located

Comment: Meanwhile you can try update 2 section code

Comment: In Ui, to access this button, click on the cookie "Accept", click on "Online programming" and that's it. All items are on the main page

Comment: Is url public ?

Comment: No, it is a test environment

Comment: But is something like https://www.kinetic.ro/ but the dropdown has the code from description

Comment: Is it like when you hover you see list of web elements pop up ? Did you try Update 2 code ?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@name='localitate']")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Bucuresti CARAMFIL");
```